# Xamarin unable to connect to Mac from Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin

I have installed Visual Studio 2013 on my Windows machine along with Xamarin. I have configured OS X Yosemite using VMWare. My Mac is working fine but when I go to connect Xamarin Mac Agent from Visual Studio, it's giving the following error

> Couldn't connect to 'Mac.local'. Please try again

My credentials are correct. I also enabled remote login option on the VM and tried with both options "All users" and "Only these users", but this did not help. How do I resolve this problem?

Comment: Can the machine resolve the IP "Mac.local"?

Answer (score 1):

Running OS X in a virtual machine is not officially supported by Xamarin as it violates Apple's licensing terms for OS X - according to these terms, OS X is only allowed to be run on genuine Apple hardware.

As well as the licensing issue, it could cause unknown issues and strange errors down the line, so this is why we do not officially support it. I would recommend grabbing a cheap Mac Mini off eBay or you could use a service like MacInCloud.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the Xamarin Studio installer on the mac (http://www.xamarin.com/download from the Mac) to install the required tools.

Also - the latest XCode (from the Appstore on the Mac) needs to be installed (before installing Xamarin Studio).